# PHP Webmatrix SQL Server Database Connection

Tags: php, sql-server, database-connection

How can I connect to MS SQL Server in PHP using Webmatrix 2?

I already have an active connection in my Databases and is already in my web.config file.

In C# the sample Code is:

```
  var db = Database.Open("MyDatabase");
  var selectedData = db.Query("SELECT * FROM myTable");
```

Is there a PHP equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from the link below:

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2010/08/04/microsoft-drivers-for-php-for-sql-server-2-0-released.aspx][1]

I was able to connect to sql server using PHP in Webmatrix 2.